# Remove collapse icon without disable collapse ability

Tags: extjs

I am using extjs grouping feature on a grid, is there a way that I can remove the collapse/expand ([+]/[-]) icon without diabling collapsible functionality.

Answer (score 0):

override css

```
.customGrid .x-grid-group-hd-collapsible .x-grid-group-title {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
    background-image: none !important; //Changed
    padding: 0 0 0 0px //Changed
}
```

then add cls: 'customGrid', to your grid